# How to sort by an indeterminate amount of variables with a Collection.sort lambda expression in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, comparator

I have a class called `Polynomial` with an iterator for each of its `Term`s, which are composed of two `int`s, `exp` and `co` (exponent and coefficient). These `Term`s are sorted in descending order by `exp` (e.g. `5x^2 + x` is a possible polynomial whereas `x + 5x^2` is not). I am trying to see if the polynomials are "weak sorted," which only checks the exponents of successive polynomials. For instance,

> 4x^3 + 2.3x + 8
> 5x^4 + 5
> 4.4x^4 + 5.4x^2 + 8.2

is weak sorted since the highest exponent in the first polynomial is less than the second, and the third is considered greater than the second because its second term has an x^2.
How can I implement this type of sorting in a Collections.sort lambda expression? I couldn't think of a way to look at each of the exponents in the Polynomial and compare them one by one. For now I just compared the first term of the first polynomial's exponent to the second's, and if those were equal, compared the cumulative sum of the exponents. This isn't correct, though, since we could have many "x" terms and have a higher cumulative sum than a polynomial with a single x^2 term that is considered greater than that under the correct definition. This is my incorrect method currently:

```
Collections.sort(weakSortedPolys,
                        (firstP, secondP) -> firstP.termList.head.term.exp < secondP.termList.head.term.exp ? -1
                                : firstP.termList.head.term.exp > secondP.termList.head.term.exp ? 1
                                        : firstP.expCumSum < secondP.expCumSum ? -1
                                                : firstP.expCumSum > secondP.expCumSum ? 1 : 0);
```

I feel like I should loop `.thenComparing`, but I'm not sure how to do that in tandem with the lambda expression, which is a requirement for my project.

Comment: So you want a kind of lexicographical sorting of the powers? See how [Arrays.compare](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/ffa11326afd5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l7336) is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't give you the answer so you can have the pleasure of getting it to work yourself. The idea is the same as if you were comparing two strings.  Advance left to right a character at a time through both strings. Compare the character pairs. As long as they're equal, keep going. When you find an unequal pair, the order of the characters gives the order of the strings. If one string runs out of characters while the other still has some, the other is greater than the one.  If you get to the end of both strings, they're equal.

As a lambda, this will look something like

```
(a, b) -> {
  for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length(), b.length()); ++i) {
    if (a.charAt(i) < b.charAt(i)) return -1;
    if (a.charAt(i) > b.charAt(i)) return +1;
  }
  return a.length() < b.length() ? -1 : a.length() > b.length() ? +1 : 0;
}
```

If your polynomials are stored as linked lists, then you'll need two pointers rather than a single index to track the terms, but the logic will be similar.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea you could put brackets like that as if it were its own method. I believe I would have come to the solution I posted earlier if I did. I was essentially trying to do all that in one line, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gene, I came up with:

```
Collections.sort(weakSortedPolys, (thisP, otherP) -> {
    Iterator<Term> thisIterator = thisP.iterator();
    Iterator<Term> otherIterator = otherP.iterator();
    while (thisIterator.hasNext()) {
        float thisTermExp = thisIterator.next().exp;
        float otherTermExp = otherIterator.next().exp;
        if (thisTermExp == otherTermExp) {
            continue;
        } else if (thisTermExp > otherTermExp) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Nice...  Glad it worked out...  This is definitely the kind of thing you'd want to cover with many unit test cases.